# Is a $G$-bundle over $\mathbb{R}$ a $G$-fibre bundle?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, fibre-bundles

Let $G$ be a Lie group with a smooth (non-transitive) action on a connected manifold $M$ (none of them need to be compact). Let further $f\in C^\infty(M,\mathbb{R})$ be $G$-invariant. Suppose that for every two open intervals $I,J\subset\mathbb{R}$ the $G$-bundles $f^{-1}(I)$ and $f^{-1}(J)$ are isomorphic, i.e., there is a map $\Phi_{I,J}\in C^\infty(f^{-1}(I),f^{-1}(J))$ which is $G$-equivariant and $f\circ\Phi_{I,J}=\phi_{I,J}\circ f$ for a map $\phi_{I,J}\in C^\infty(I,J)$.

**Qustion:** Is it true that $M\overset{f}\to\mathbb{R}$ is isomorphic to the trivial $G$-bundle $\mathbb{R}\times f^{-1}(0)$? Or does there exist a map $\Phi\in C^\infty(M,f^{-1}(0))$ which is $G$-equivariant and $f\circ\Phi=1_\mathbb{R}$?

**Discussion:** Since every locally trivial (fibre) bundle over $\mathbb{R}$ is trivial, it is enough to find only a local trivialization.

It is hard to check if the $G$-action on $M$ is proper, so the orbit structure of an invariant leaf $f^{-1}(t)$ may not be very neat. But it is the same for all such leaves, and the question basically boils down to finding a smooth section in the "orbit space bundle", which need not be a smooth bundle? This becomes too subtle, and I hope that there are higher level arguments to show this.

If $M$ admits a smooth cross section to the $G$-action, that is, a submanifold $S\subset M$ such that $\{gS\}_{g\in G}$ is a partition of $M$, and if $S\overset{f}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a trivial bundle then I think that the answer is positive. But I am not sure if this would be too optimistic.

Thank you.